# IKBone rotates and inverts trying to follow pole when spine is rotated

Tags: rigging

How can I avoid this problem when rotating the spine:
[image]

---

If spine is not rotated, IK works "fine" with Pole Angle: 0, is this correct?
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Answered: I had "Inherit Rotation" turned off as the tutorial I followed said.
I just turned on again and now works as expected:

[image]